# mongodb FINDBYIDANDUPDATE() is not returning the updated document

Tags: node.js, mongodb

hello I am trying to update a document on mongodb but everytime I run the lambda function below it does not return the new document but returns a http response 200. I have tried to update the logic in so many forms but I get the response 200 but the update does not happen. The lambda function takes 2 path parameters i.e the userid and the date to find the specific plan then updates it... It neither updates nor returns the new document. Please help!

```
const Plan = require('../../model/planModel');
const User = require('../../model/userModel');
const { connectDB } = require('../../config/db');
const { verify, decode } = require('jsonwebtoken');
const { decode_token } = require('../../utils');
const { findByIdAndUpdate } = require('../../model/planModel');

exports.handler = async (event) => {
  try {
    await connectDB();
    //console.log(event)

    const { userid, date } = event.pathParameters;
    const exists = await Plan.findOne(userid, date);
    console.log('I made it here: ', exists);

    const {
      excitedAbout,
      gratefulForMorning,
      mainThreeTodo,
      dailyToDo,
      meals,
      water,
      exercise,
      meditation,
      relaxation,
      happyScale,
      happyMoment,
      gratefulForTonight,
      dailyQuestion,
    } = event.body;

    const updatedPlan = await Plan.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: exists._id },
      {
        excitedAbout: excitedAbout,
        gratefulForMorning: gratefulForMorning,
        mainThreeTodo: mainThreeTodo,
        dailyToDo: dailyToDo,
        meals: meals,
        water: water,
        exercise: exercise,
        meditation: meditation,
        relaxation: relaxation,
        happyScale: happyScale,
        happyMoment: happyMoment,
        gratefulForTonight: gratefulForTonight,
        dailyQuestion: dailyQuestion,
      },
      { new: true }
    );

    console.log('this is a plan', updatedPlan);
    return {
      statusCode: 200,
      headers: {
        'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
      },
      body: JSON.stringify(updatedPlan),
    };
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
};
```

This is the data I want to update:

```
{
    "user": "62d1a251806d10095ff0f0a6",
    "date": "2022-09-09T18:30:00.000Z",
    "excitedAbout": "Excited About something",
    "gratefulForMorning": "",
    "mainThreeTodo": [
        {
            "text": "HELLO I survived",
            "checked": false
        },
        {
            "text": "",
            "checked": false
        },
        {
            "text": "",
            "checked": false
        }
    ],
    "dailyToDo": [
        {
            "text": "",
            "checked": false
        },
        {
            "text": "",
            "checked": false
        },
        {
            "text": "",
            "checked": false
        }
    ],
    "meals": {
        "breakfast": [
            {
                "meal": "",
                "calories": ""
            }
        ],
        "lunch": [
            {
                "meal": "",
                "calories": ""
            }
        ],
        "dinner": [
            {
                "meal": "skuma",
                "calories": ""
            }
        ]
    },
    "water": 7,
    "exercise": false,
    "relaxation": false,
    "meditation": false,
    "happyScale": 0,
    "happyMoment": "",
    "gratefulForTonight": "",
    "dailyQuestion": {
        "question": "",
        "answer": ""
    }
}
```

and this is what I'm getting

```
{
  "meals": {
    "breakfast": [
      {
        "meal": "",
        "calories": "",
        "_id": "631cc36ed9e6f6711e7da2c3"
      }
    ],
    "lunch": [
      {
        "meal": "",
        "calories": "",
        "_id": "631cc36ed9e6f6711e7da2c2"
      }
    ],
    "dinner": [
      {
        "meal": "",
        "calories": "",
        "_id": "631cc36ed9e6f6711e7da2c1"
      }
    ]
  },
  "dailyQuestion": {
    "question": "",
    "answer": ""
  },
  "_id": "631ba3e559b8a53d732a1958",
  "user": "62d1a251806d10095ff0f0a6",
  "date": "2022-09-09T18:30:00.000Z",
  "excitedAbout": "",
  "gratefulForMorning": "",
  "mainThreeTodo": [
    {
      "text": "",
      "checked": false,
      "_id": "631cc36ed9e6f6711e7da2bb"
    },
    {
      "text": "",
      "checked": false,
      "_id": "631cc36ed9e6f6711e7da2bc"
    },
    {
      "text": "",
      "checked": false,
      "_id": "631cc36ed9e6f6711e7da2bd"
    }
  ],
  "dailyToDo": [
    {
      "text": "",
      "checked": false,
      "_id": "631cc36ed9e6f6711e7da2be"
    },
    {
      "text": "",
      "checked": false,
      "_id": "631cc36ed9e6f6711e7da2bf"
    },
    {
      "text": "",
      "checked": false,
      "_id": "631cc36ed9e6f6711e7da2c0"
    }
  ],
  "water": 0,
  "exercise": false,
  "meditation": false,
  "relaxation": false,
  "happyScale": 0,
  "happyMoment": "",
  "gratefulForTonight": "",
  "createdAt": "2022-09-09T20:36:53.680Z",
  "updatedAt": "2022-09-13T12:01:02.966Z",
  "__v": 0
}
```

it's like it is never passed

Comment: Instead of `Plan.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: exists._id}, ...`, should it be `Plan.findByIdAndUpdate( exists._id, ...`?

Comment: i'm still not getting the updated document...it's like the update never happened

Comment: @FaithOkoth does it _actually_ never happen, or aren't you just getting the updated document back? Those are two different things.

Answer (score 0):

Your query seems to be missing the update operators, that's why it might not be working for you:

```
  const updatedPlan = await Plan.findByIdAndUpdate(
      { _id: exists._id },
      {
        $set: {
          excitedAbout: excitedAbout,
          gratefulForMorning: gratefulForMorning,
          mainThreeTodo: mainThreeTodo,
          dailyToDo: dailyToDo,
          meals: meals,
          water: water,
          exercise: exercise,
          meditation: meditation,
          relaxation: relaxation,
          happyScale: happyScale,
          happyMoment: happyMoment,
          gratefulForTonight: gratefulForTonight,
          dailyQuestion: dailyQuestion,
        }
      },
      { new: true }
    );
```

Try this, here we have specified the `$set` update operator.